# On/Off Switch in Menu not returning state programmatically

Tags: java, android, menu, menuitem

I have added on/off switch in menu. I want to toast "Switch is OFF" if switch is "OFF". But It's not working when i power on switch from menu.I have tried to debug it, the code is not going inside if statement  " if (id==R.id.myswitch) ".  I have tried to put simple button control it's working that "Button is clicked". But switch is not working.

I have inflated layout "switch_layout.xml" in the menuitem

Here is xml and code:

switch_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchForActionBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MyActivity" >

     <item
        android:id="@+id/myswitch"
        android:title=""
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
    />   
</menu>
```

code

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

         if (id==R.id.myswitch){

            Switch onOff=(Switch) item.getActionView();
            if( onOff.isChecked()==false){

//Toast that switch is off
            }

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: A `Switch` that changes upon menu click or is it a `Toast` to explain what's obvious? I personally don't get it -- seems like a bad UI/UX pattern IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (id == R.id.myswitch) {
        View view = item.getActionView();
        if (view != null) {
            Switch onOff = (Switch) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);
            if (onOff!=null) {
                if (onOff.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Switch is ON",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Switch is OFF",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Switch is null",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "view is null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

try this code if it works but i'm not sure if it works. its just a guess.

or you can try below code.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

boolean bSwitch=false;
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int id = menu.getItem(0).getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.myswitch) {
        if (bSwitch) {
            menu.getItem(0).setTitle("smthng is ON");
        }
        else {
            menu.getItem(0).setTitle("smthng is OFF");
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.myswitch) {
        if (bSwitch) {
            bSwitch=false;
        }
        else {
            bSwitch=true;
        }

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.newshunt.news.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/myswitch"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="smthng is OFF"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (id==R.id.myswitch){

            Switch onOff=(Switch) item.getActionView();
          //  if( onOff.isChecked()==false){
            if ( !onOff.isChecked())
                 //Toast that switch is off
            }

 }
```

try the above code and check which ID is getID() is returning